# Uncaught type error jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code keep throwing error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

It happen if no URL enter to textbox . It works fine but keep throw that error .

How can I make this error gone ?

Here my code:

```
$('.ver').on('keyup', function(){
if($(this).val().match(/\b(https?):\/\/([\-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i)[0].toString().length > 24)
//do something
});
```

I only need 1 line if condition .(qcube jQuery condition)

Comment: You need to check if the result of `val()` and `.match(..)` is undefined or null, and then perform any operation on it.

Comment: So check, if you actually have a value, before applying operations to it ...

Comment: @ShaunakD how ? i need to check length more than match .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** will return  null if there were no matches. So you need to check that

```
$('.ver').on('keyup', function() {
  var match = $(this).val().match(/\b(https?):\/\/([\-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i);
  if (match)
    if (match[0].toString().length > 24)
    //do something
});
```

or

```
$('.ver').on('keyup', function() {
  var match = $(this).val().match(/\b(https?):\/\/([\-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i);
  if (match? match[0].toString().length > 24 : false)
  //do something
});
```

Also you can use **[`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)** operator

```
$('.ver').on('keyup', function() {
  var match = $(this).val().match(/\b(https?):\/\/([\-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i);
  if (match && match[0].toString().length > 24 )
  //do something
});
```

It will only evaluate second expression if first expression is returns true

Comment: I not able to do like this . I only need 1 line if condition .(qcube jquery condition)

Comment: cant be like this ? $(this).val().match(/\b(https?):\/\/([\-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i) ?
        $(this).val().match(/\b(https?):\/\/([\-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i)[0].toString().length > 24 :false

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null(anonymous function) @ VM6145:11f.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3f.event.add.h.handle.i @ jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3

Comment: I already try && before . still not working thanks . mark as answer cause it work on jsfiddle .